# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a web application using Html5 and jquery. I'm getting this "`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #chapter?book=Exod&num=1`" error when I'm trying to navigate from current page to another page `<div data-role="page" id="chapter">`

My Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

          for (var x in books) {
            if (x.indexOf('_')>=0) {
                var items = '<li><a href="#chapter?book='+ x.substring(1) +'&num=1">'+ books[x].bname +'</a></li>';
            }
            $("#book_list").append(items);
        }
         $('#book_list').find(':jqmData(role=listview)').listview();

    });

// Listen for pagebeforechange event
    $(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( data ) {
        // only handle changePage() when loading a page by URL.
        if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
            // Handle URLs that requests chapter page
            var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ), regex = /^#chapter/;
            if ( url.hash.search(regex) !== -1 ) {
                showChapter( url, data.options );
                // tell changePage() we've handled this 
                //e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you make sure `regex` is correctly escaped?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6p3x/16/ this is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is incorrectly formatted:

```
#chapter?book=Exod&num=1
```

Try to replace the `#` with a `$` for instance.

---

So the following line

```
var items = '<li><a href="#chapter?book='+ x.substring(1) +'&num=1">'+ books[x].bname +'</a></li>';
```

becomes

```
var items = '<li><a href="$chapter?book='+ x.substring(1) +'&num=1">'+ books[x].bname +'</a></li>';
```

and this other one:

```
var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ), regex = /^#chapter/;
```

becomes

```
var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ), regex = /^$chapter/;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NVLbH/)

Comment: getting "Error loading message"... #chapter is navigation page id please check my html and code in fiddle.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a demo.Run it. You'll notice an error message : "Error Loading Page". The browser is trying to load something like http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/$chapter?book=XXX where XXX is the bok name. So bring back the code on YOUR server and retest it there.

Comment: yes i changed my code with your demo but i'm giving the correct path of the book and its not loading

Comment: I'd suggest you now to use a browser like Chrome and its DevTools for investigating on the specific problem you are facing.

Comment: Yes i'm using firefox firebug...its not showing any errors.. just showing the message on the screen as "Error in loading"...but i gave the correct path of the books